# editor able to find not included file c++

Tags: visual-c++

My code :
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace file {
#include "file.cpp"
}
namespace file2 {
#include "file1.cpp"
}

int main() {
    file::hello();
    return 0;
}
```

file.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
void hello() {
    std::cout << "hello";
}
```

file1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
void hello() {
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

My problem:

I use virtual studio, and i don't know why this does not work.I try it allready on CodeBlock and it was fine. But in VS i have error with `at least one repeatedly defined symbol has been found`.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Your include file should have *.h extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since VS still builds and links file.cpp and file1.cpp to the executable you get the errors. You can exclude them from the project by changing its properties or make them regular header files and include them as such.
The include will literally just copy the content of the file into the name space declaration of main.cpp.

Comment: Thanks, i exclude them from project like you said and it`s works.